# Nested form fields dissappear when validate => true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many, client-side-validation

I have two models with a has_many :through relationship. For some time the form has been working just fine. I decided to work on client-side validations, at which point attribute access permissions started to appear.

Here are the models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :missions, :through => :participations
  has_many :participations
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :participations
end

class Mission < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :users, :through => :participations
  has_many :participations
end

class Participation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :mission
  belongs_to :user
end
```

`

Here's the form (where resource is a User):

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :validate => true) do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :missions do |ff| %>
     ....
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Which results in 
`client_side_validation_hash' for nil:NilClass)`
If I remove the :validate => true, the form displays fine. This leads me to believe there is an issue with resource seeing mission attributes. Any modifications I make to the models results in the Mission fields not being displayed in the form.

I've looked at several similar questions here with answers (which is where I some ideas from), but none work for me. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

change the line

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :validate => true) do |f| %>
```

to

```
<%= form_for(@user, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :validate => true) do |f| %>
```